# SoX commands for Windows

Tags: python, sox

I have these SoX commands that work on Linux, but not on Windows because the Windows version does not ship with `play` or `rec` anymore. How can I rework these to use only `sox`?

```
rec -c 1 -r 48k -q -n noiseprof - trim 0 5
rec -c 1 -r 48k -q -t flac - noisered - 0.21 silence -l 1 0.0 1% 1 3.0 5% pad 1 0
play -t mp3 - -q
```

I'm using them in Python for speech recognition and would like to use a statement like this

```
sox = shutil.which('sox') or glob.glob('C:\Program Files*\sox*\sox.exe')[0]
```

to make it platform independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exerpt from sox manual:

> The play and rec commands are provided so that basic playing and recording is as simple as
>
> `play existing-file.wav`
>
> and
>
> `rec new-file.wav`
>
> These two commands are functionally equivalent to
>
> `sox existing-file.wav -d`
>
> and
>
> `sox -d new-file.wav`

The -d option means to select the default audio device for input (if it comes first) or output (if comes last).

Comment: Can you provide a reference to this in some online documentation, it'd help validate the answer.

Comment: This works! Go ahead and tell me RTFM. I did browse through it, but I swear I never saw this. Thank you!

Comment: this works for windows i tried and didnt work play and rec.

Comment: i cant with with this way